# Is it possible to get all channels a slack bot is allowed to write?

Tags: python, heroku, slack-api

I am trying to build a slack bot based on heroku and python which writes messages every 10 minutes to all channels the bot is allowed to write messages. It would be perfect if I could just read from the slack api to which channelId's the bot is connected and let the bot post the message to all channels at the same time.

Till now I couldnt find such function in the slack api. On the other hand I have to addmit that I am pretty new to slack. Is there a similiar function out there or can you think of a work around? If possible I would like to avoid storing data additionally somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is. Call [`users.conversations`](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.conversations) with your bot token to get the list of channels it is a member of.

From the documentation:

> This method helps answer questions like:
>
> ```
> Which conversations am I a member of?
> Which public channels is my bot user in?
> Do I have any direct messages open with my friend Suzy?
> Is my bot a member of any private channels?
> ```